# How do I display a triangle next to subsections in the table of contents?

Tags: beamer

I have a simple presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace{1.2 em}\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection \\}


\begin{document}

\section{A}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}

\subsection{A.1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A.2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The table of contents looks like this

[image: table of contents]

How do I display the standard Beamer triangle that the `itemize` environment uses (under the settings I'm using, i.e. `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]`).

p120 of the [Beamer user guide](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) implies that the symbol is `$\blacktriangleright$`, but at the risk of stating the obvious, that displays a *black* triangle. That ignore the color theme I specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can colour the black triangle, for example `\textcolor{structure.fg}{$\blacktriangleright$}` will colour it in the blue colour which is the default colour of the itemize items.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\textcolor{structure.fg}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hspace{1.2 em}\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection \\}


\begin{document}

\section{A}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}

\subsection{A.1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A.2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]