Custom beamer table of contents with different version at the beginning versus between sections
I would like to change the beamer table of contents. I want two versions, one version that appears at the beginning of the presentation and another between sections.
Here is a sample document:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\title{beamertemp}
\author{me}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Title 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}{Title 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title 4}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}

\begin{frame}{Title 5}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title 6}
\end{frame}

Currently, this is what the first table of contents looks like:

And this is what the between-section table of contents looks like:

What I want is for the first table of contents to look like this (with multiple columns that are filled if the presentation is large enough):

Code for that frame:
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\bullet$}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.05\textwidth}
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.1in}
        \item Section 1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Title 1
            \item Title 2
        \end{itemize}
        
        \item Section 2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Title 3
            \item Title 4
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.1in}
        \item Section 3
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Title 5
            \item Title 6
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \column{0.05\linewidth}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

And the between-section table of contents should look like this (the section being entered is in black and the others in light gray):

Code for that frame:
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \textbf{\color{black}\Large Section 1}
    \vfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}\Large Section 2}
    \vfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}\Large Section 3}
    \vfill
\end{frame}

How might I go about achieving this?


to split the main toc into multiple columns, you have two options: either split in manually by using beamer columns (recommended) or automatically with the multicol package (I wouldn't do this because the column break will probably be at a bad location, e.g. in the centre of a section)

use the hideallsubsections option to hide the subsections from the sections tocs

use \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black} to switch to black colour for the section tocs



\documentclass[aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

\title{beamertemp}
\author{me}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[sections={-2}]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[sections={3-}]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 4}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 5}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title 6}
\end{frame}
\end{document}




Thanks, this gets me really close. For the between-section ToC I added \centering, \bfseries, and \Large to get the style I wanted. For the main ToC, is it possible to (1) add the bullet points as I showed in my example and (2) use frame titles rather than subsections?

@jared (2) use a subsection for each frame. That's way less hacky than adding frametitles to the toc. However if you insist: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer

@jared (1) change the section in toc templates to however they should look like in the toc, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395727/36296
